# Auto-convert DateTimeOffset to UTC when querying PostgreSQL with EFCore

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an entity like that:

```cs
public class Datum
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset TimeStamp { get; set; }
}
```

When I want to query that `Timestamp` with the following code:

```cs
var now = DateTimeOffset.Now;
var data = await Context.Data.Where(d => d.TimeStamp > now).ToListAsync();
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot write DateTimeOffset with Offset=02:00:00 to PostgreSQL type 'timestamp with time zone', only offset 0 (UTC) is supported. Note that it's not possible to mix DateTimes with different Kinds in an array/range. See the Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior AppContext switch to enable legacy behavior.

The same is happening when I want to add `Datum` values that way:

```cs
var now = DateTimeOffset.Now;
Context.Data.Add(new Datum()
{
    TimeStamp = now,
});

await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I know I just could use `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow` but my real software is a bit more complex and I don't want to convert it every time manually with e.g. `now.UtcDateTime`. I just want EFCore to auto-convert each `DateTimeOffset` object to one in UTC-time without doing it manually on each update and query.

Comment: You cannot mix Timestamp and TimeZone.  See : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html

Comment: I don't really get it. Where di I mix Timestamp and TimeZone?

Comment: That is what the exception says.  Check the dbContext to see what type you are using for Timestamp (not Datum table but Data table).

Comment: The issue says I need to convert my Timestamp to UTC but I don't want to do that manually. When I use `DatetimeOffset.UtcNow` everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to do it in the get/set

```
public class Datum
    {
        public DateTime timeUTC { get; set; }

        public long Id { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset TimeStamp 
        { 
            get {return timeUTC.ToLocalTime() ; }
            set {timeUTC = value.UtcDateTime ; } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: But this still does not resolve my issue in queries.

Comment: It does what you asked which is automatically convert a DateTime to a TimeStamp; and automatically converts a TimeStamp to a DateTime.